# Find when integral of an interpolated function is equal to a specific value (python)

Tags: python, scipy

I have arrays `t_array` and `dMdt_array` of x and y points. Let's call `M = trapz(dMdt_array, t_array)`. I want to find at what value of t the integral of dM/dt vs t is equal to a certain value -- say `0.05*M`. In python, is there a nice way to do this?

I was thinking something like `F = interp1d(t_array, dMdt_array)`. Then some kind of root find for where the integral of F is equal to 0.05*M. Can I do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to use the CubicSpline class instead. Then it's `CubicSpline(x, y).antiderivative().solve(0.05*M)` or thereabouts.

Comment: Looks like `solve` will find roots outside the limits of `x` by default, so if that is undesirable, it might be a good idea to use `.solve(0.05*M, extrapolate=False)`.

Comment: hmm when I do `from scipy import interpolate` and `interpolate.CubicSpline(x, y).antiderivative().solve(0.05*M)`, I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CubicSpline'`.

Comment: @Jamie yes, CubicSpline is new in SciPy 0.17